# Type '{ children: Element; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ReactNode'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Got this error here:

> Type '{ children: Element; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ReactNode'.

```js
export const withAppProvider = (Component: AppComponent) => {
  return function WrapperComponent(props: any) {
    return (
      <AppProvider> // <-- here
        <Component {...props} />
      </AppProvider>
    );
  };
};
```

Maybe something wrong with `AppProvider` declaration?

```js
export const AppProvider = (children: ReactNode) => {
  const { width, height } = useWindowSize();
  const isClient = useClient();
  const isMobile = isClient ? width < 1200 : false;

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        isClient,
        isMobile,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

---

got this with `export const AppProvider = (children: React.ReactNode) => {`

```
Type error: Type '{ children: Element; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ReactNode'.
  Type '{ children: Element; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': key, type, props
```

Comment: try change : `children: React.ReactNode` and can you provide interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is defined as `children` prop the problem goes away.

```
interface IProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}
export const AppProvider = ({children}: IProps ) => {}
```

Comment: It is very unfortunate that this works.